# Windows rights for write access

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, directory

I have an infuriating problem with directories in a partition that I use to share documents between Linux and Windows. This partition has several directories (all the usual top level user directories: Documents, Downloads, Pictures, Videos, etc.). Under both OS's, I point the relevant directories there. For instance, in Ubuntu, I mount this partition under /DATA and then

```
ln -s /DATA/Documents ~/Documents  
ln -s /DATA/Downloads ~/Downloads
```

This has been my way of doing stuff for years and has always worked up to my most recent laptop. In the present case, all directories on the partition work *except* for Documents. I get the following rights (when I ls in /DATA)

```
dr-xr-xr-x  1 myuname myuname   16384 Feb 17  2020  Documents
drwxrwxrwx  1 myuname myuname  131072 Feb 16 19:17  Downloads
```

All directories on the partition show up the same way as Downloads, only Documents is acting up.

Because other directories in the same partition work fine, my guess is that this is something coming from Windows. I have tried (in Windows) changing the rights on the entire partition from Windows, changing the rights specifically to the Documents folder.. nothing has worked so far.

Although this is Windows related, it is a problem that only arises under Linux, so I thought I would ask here to see if anybody has had the same issue and found a workaround.

(For info, I have also tried to disable Windows fastboot, that did not change anything. Seemed like a long shot, anyway, since it's not the entire partition that acts up.)

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** add the user `Everyone` to the file created in windows (or the whole folder), with the requested operation mode (read, write, execute..) at the security tab.
Sometimes when it comes to web apps or shares, the `Anonymous` user credentials also need to be added.

If you would like to make files accessible by unknown users, you need to set appropriate credentials on the folders and files created by that system.
Those credentials stick to files and folders when moving from one system to another, and translated accordingly when it comes to windows-linux.

Just like in linux when you use chown/chmod to set owners and access type for "other" users, you need to do the same for every file created by windows, as it is not the default credential for new files unless you decide it to be so (inherited by folder or filesystem credentials for example).
This is done by default security reasons by windows (default security policy).